# CASE clause in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I'm doing a leetcode question. 2 similar answers are worked out. But I have no idea why one is wrong and the other is right. The following is the question link. The goal is writing a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

https://leetcode.com/problems/consecutive-numbers/

The table looks like

```
| Id | Num |
|----|-----|
| 1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 3  |  1  |
| 4  |  2  |
| 5  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |
| 7  |  2  |
```

Right version:

```
select distinct Num as ConsecutiveNums
from Logs, (select @prev := -1, @count := 0) as Init
where (@count := case when @prev = (@prev := Num) then @count + 1 else 1 end) >= 3
```

The output:

```
| ConsecutiveNums |
|-----------------|
|       1         |
```

Wrong version:

```
select distinct Num as ConsecutiveNums
from Logs, (select @prev := -1, @count := 0) as Init
where (case when @prev = (@prev := Num) then @count := @count + 1 else @count :=  1 end) >= 3
```

The output:

```
| ConsecutiveNums |
|-----------------|
|       1         |
|       2         |
```

The only difference is @count := is moved into **case end**.

It seems that **else** part causes some error, which cannot be explained by my knowledge.

Comment: You need to supply some sample data where the queries fails and succeed in the question and not via a link.

Comment: *"But I have no idea why"*: that is surprising, since the second one compares with -10..... Seems trivial?

Comment: Anyway, neither is correct, because they both assume that the records will be visited in order of `Num`, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: With no sample data or results, this question is unclear.  The link goes to a site with a SQL Server example, but the question is clearly about MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I just updated the question making it well formed. @Gordon

Comment: Tables are added and one typo is fixed. Thanks for helping me out. @Joakim

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I fixed it and added an example. @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version of the code doesn't work for a rather obscure reason. This part:

```
else @count :=  1
```

... has an expression that has no dynamic component. MySql optimises its execution plan in a way that it does not perform that assignment a second time, but just returns the current value of `@count`. This is because MySql variables are really not designed to be modified *during* the execution of a query. When you still decide to use that side-effect, you must be aware of such "optimisation" behaviour.

You can try to force MySql into making the assignment *every* time. This can be done by including a variable or field reference in the assigned expression. For instance you could use `:= if(@count, 1, 1)` instead of just `:= 1`. The result is the same (always 1), but now it will be re-evaluated and assigned each time it is encountered:

```
where (case when @prev = (@prev := Num)  
            then @count := @count + 1
            else @count := if(@count, 1, 1)
       end) >= 3
```

You could think of other alternative expressions, like `:= 1+Num*0`, as long as there is a reference to some variable/field, it will solve the issue.

Looking at the first version of the query you provided, you'll see that there the expression assigned to `@count` already has such dynamic content.

All in all, setting variables in a query is not advised, and future versions of MySql may no longer support it, as is stated in the [Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than `SET`. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you! It is what I eagerly want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not comparing the ">= 3" with count. Which is what we are trying to test against for the 3 consecutive numbers. In the wrong version not sure why there was "= - 10" though. The corrected version of the "wrong" version is:

```
SELECT num AS ConsecutiveNums
FROM   logs,
       (SELECT @prev := -1,
               @count := 0) AS Init
WHERE ( @count := CASE
           WHEN @prev = ( @prev := num ) THEN @count := @count + 1
           ELSE @count
         end ) >= 3
```

I also added a different test case just to make sure:

```
{"headers": {"Logs": ["Id", "Num"]}, "rows": {"Logs": [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 6], [5, 2], [6, 2], [7, 2]]}}
```

The default one without changing the test case gives "1" this test case should return "2"

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my question making it readable. My bad. Now I tested both right and wrong versions, which give the above result. Wish you could help me again.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @max_id INTEGER
SET @max_id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seat)

SELECT CASE WHEN id < @max_id THEN case when id%2<>0 then id+1 when id%2=0 then id-1 end
            WHEN id = @max_id THEN case when id%2=0 then id-1 else id
       END id
      ,student
FROM seat
ORDER BY id
```

SET @max_id = (SELECT max(id) FROM seat)
SELECT
CASE
WHEN id!=@max_id THEN
CASE
WHEN id%2!=0  THEN id+1
WHEN id%2=0 THEN id-1
END
WHEN id= @max_id THEN
CASE
WHEN id%2=0  THEN id-1
WHEN id%2!=0 THEN id
END
END id
, student
FROM seat
ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table If Not Exists Logs (id int, num int)
Truncate table Logs
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('1', '1')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('2', '1')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('3', '1')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('4', '2')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('5', '1')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('6', '2')
insert into Logs (id, num) values ('7', '2')
```

**Using Joins:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT l1.Num AS ConsecutiveNums
FROM Logs l1,
     Logs l2,
     Logs l3
WHERE l1.Id + 1 = l2.Id
  AND l2.Id + 1 = l3.Id
  AND l1.Num = l2.Num
  AND l2.Num = l3.Num
```

[image: test-case-leetcode]

Answer (score -1):

If consecutively means that the ids increment by "1" (as in the example data), then variables are not needed -- or even desired:

```
select t1.num
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.id = t1.id + 1 and t2.num = t1.num join
     t t3
     on t3.id  = t1.id + 2 and t3.num = t1.num;
```

If you have more than three consecutive values or a `num` that matches multiple rows, then you might want `select distinct num`.

Comment: Why would this get a downvote?  It solves the problem that the OP wants to solve.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this solution, but now what I wonder is why the location of user-defined variable may cause unexpected results.  I don't know who gives a downvote but it seems the answer is not relevant to my question. @Gordon

Comment: @KUNZHOU . . . You really don't want to use variables if you can avoid them.  And this answers the question that you asked:  "The goal is writing a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively."